# Excel: Sum up a column based on conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet with such columns:

```
A    B    C    D
1    1    X    INT
2    1    X    INT
1    2    Y    INT
2    2    Y    INT
3    2    Y    INT
1    3    Z    INT
2    3    Z    INT
3    3    Z    INT
4    3    Z    INT
```

Column D has values that I want to sum up.
Column A always counts up from 1, based on the group it is in (column B) and has maximum values of either 2 (group 1), 3 (group 2) or 4 (group 3)
Let's say scenario 1 is "Sum up all INTs), if C=X and and the maximum value is 2.
Colum C is just a condition that will have to be met. Of course, everything can be in many variations.

Probably it will have to work with =SUMIF(), but the best I could come up with so far is
=SUMIF(D:D, C:C, "X")

But that won't work, if there is another group that has condition X, but may have more values in Column A.

My idea is to use COUNTIF() and see if a group has on the whole 2, 3, or 4 values.

But how can I make that more general??

Thanks a lot!

[EDIT:]
I also thought of a way to check with AND(), OR() and NOT() if, for every group that has max. 3 counts (col. A) that there is 1, 2, 3 but not 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12.

Number of groups (C) could be infinite (although usually not more than 7). Counts of col. a are either 3, 7 or 12
As i mentioned, there could be a group with condition X that has 3 counts and another group with condition X that has 7 counts, and for both scenarios, column D gets summed up according to the conditions.

The problem is that group X has counts 1, 2 (with max. 2) and another possible group F could also have condition X, but 12 counts. That means count 1 and 2 may not be counted twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D1:D9,(F2=COUNTIFS(B1:B9,B1:B9))*(C1:C9=F1)
```

This iterates the values row by row, returning the value in D where C is equal to the desire constraint, `X` in this case and the count of B is equal to the number of items.

[image]

Comment: That does not work for me, although I think that your solution might be the one I will use. Still, there seems to be something wrong with the code. When I type that example the way it is, then I also get a returned value of 30 when F2=2. But When I type F2=3, then the returned value is 0?

Comment: You also need to cahnge the category to `Y`. You stated you want both constraints

Comment: @Khaled you may 'accept' the answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to remove this question from stackExchange 'unanswered' list. ( :

Comment: @Scott-Craner How would I change the code, if I want to know how many times a count occurs, regardless of group or condition X?